# Given the pdf $f(y\mid\theta) = \theta y^{\theta - 1}1_{0<y<1}$, show $E\left(\frac{1}{2\theta\sum_{i = 1}^n W_i}\right) = \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ be a random sample from the pdf $$f(y\mid\theta) = \theta y^{\theta - 1}, 0 < y < 1, \theta > 0 .$$
show that $$E\left(\frac{1}{2\theta\sum_{i = 1}^n W_i}\right) = \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$$

I have showed that $\sum_{i = 1}^n -\ln(Y_i)$ is sufficient for $\theta$, and if $W_i = -\ln(Y_i)$, I have showed that $W_i$ has an exponential distribution with mean $1/\theta$. I have also showed that $2\theta \sum_{i=1}^n W_i $ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom.

I am wondering how to show it?

Comment: What are the $W_i$ and how are they related to the $Y_i$?

Comment: I just add more info in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the chi-square distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is $$f(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac k 2\right)}\left(\frac x 2\right)^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2}\,\frac{dx}{2}\text{ for }x>0,$$ then it's just evaluating an integral:

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac 1 x f(x)\,dx & =
\int_0^\infty \frac 1 x \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac k 2\right)}\left(\frac x 2\right)^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2}\,\frac{dx}{2} \\[12pt]
& = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k/2)}\cdot\frac 1 2 \int_0^\infty \left(\frac x 2\right)^{k/2-2} e^{-x/2} \,\frac{dx}{2} \\[12pt]
& = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k/2)}\cdot\frac 1 2 \int_0^\infty u^{k/2-2} e^{-u}\,du \\[12pt]
& = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k/2)}\cdot\frac 1 2 \cdot \Gamma\left( \frac k 2 - 1 \right) \\[12pt]
& = \frac{1}{\frac k 2 - 1} \cdot\frac 1 2 = \frac{1}{k-2}. 
\end{align}

Comment: When I take $$E\left(\frac{1}{2\theta\sum_{i = 1}^n W_i}\right)$$
I got to $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\theta\sum_{i=1}^n - ln(Y_i)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\frac{1}{2^n}  y^{n-1} e^{-y/2} dy$$

I am wondering how to combine the y terms?

Comment: You say you've already shown that $2\theta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n -\ln Y_i\right)$ has a chi-square distribution.  That's all the "combining of $Y$ terms" you need to do. You say you want the expected value of its reciprocal.  That means you need to integrate $1/y$ times the chi-square density as a function of $y$.  The expression involving the sum of the $Y_i$ should not be there unless you're working with the _joint_ density of $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ rather than with the density of $2\theta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n -\ln Y_i\right)$.

Comment: A follow up question, how to use this result to find the minimum-variance unbiased estimator (MVUE) for $\theta$?

Comment: Since you've got $\mathbb E\left(\dfrac{1}{2\theta\sum_{i=1}^n W_i}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2(n-1)}$, it follows that $\mathbb E\left(\dfrac{n-1}{\sum_{i=1}^n W_i}\right)=\theta$, so $\dfrac{n-1}{\sum_{i=1}^n W_i}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. If you've also proved completeness and sufficiency, then you have the UMVUE.

Comment: what do you mean by completeness?

Comment: "Complete" means admitting no unbiased estimator of zero.  To say that $\sum_{i=1}^n W_i$ is a complete statistic means that there is no function of that statistic not depending on $\theta$, whose expected value remains $0$ as $\theta$ changes (except the trivial case: the function whose value is everywhere zero).  An assumption of completeness is usually involved in proving that a particular statistic is a UMVUE.

Comment: Clarification: It's an "assumption" in a _theorem_ that says that a statistic that is complete, sufficient, and unbiased is a UMVUE; but in any particular case to which the theorem is applied, it's not just an "assumption", but is something requiring proof.

Comment: For this question, do we need to prove it?

Comment: Maybe that depends on whether you need to prove uniqueness.  If we say that $\int_0^\infty g(x) f(x\mid\theta)\,dx=0$ regardless of the value of $\theta>0$, then the question is whether that implies $g(x)=0$ regardless of the value of $x>0$.  I think after a bit of algebra that might reduce to invertibility of the Laplace transform.